# Does gcc 4.8.1 enable sse by default?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc4.8

I experienced crashes running an old code of mine on a system which doesn't support SSE4.1, I debugged a bit and found SSE instructions in the glibc, is that possible? Why isn't this reported in gcc 4.8.1 release notes?

Comment: glibc isn't gcc and vice versa. Where exactly did you see what ?

Comment: any string compare function

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can see what optimizations are used by GCC with the following command:

```
$ gcc -Q --help=target
```

For instance, on my machine, GCC does not enable sse4.1 by default:

```
$ gcc -Q --help=target | grep msse4.1
  -msse4.1                              [disabled]
```

However, it is supported because it appears in `/proc/cpuinfo`. And indeed, if I ask GCC to optimize the generated code for my machine, it enables sse4.1:

```
$ gcc -Q --help=target -march=native | grep msse4.1
  -msse4.1                              [enabled]
```

Comment: I forgot all about these options - I wish I could upvote multiple times.

Comment: This should be the answer of the day! Didn't know about this! Thanks!